# WebContent folder empty when deployed

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a web project in which I have a different folder for holding jsps, Web-Inf folder structure and the css. The folder name is called `WebRoot`. When I deploy the project through eclipse (no matter what server I am using), it will deploy a war file with an empty WebContent folder(means there are no jsps, css files and configuration files) it leaves the `WebContent` folder empty cause everything is in WebRoots folder and that's why, after the deployment, when I hit the browser, I am always looking at the error called `404 Not Found`...

How to tell Eclipse to load the contents of the WebRoot folder in WebContent folder? Is their a way? If there are any, please explain them.

OR

Should I change the folder of these file's but then there are many different configuration file's which off I am unaware and I have to change the whole in thing their as well.

JFYGI(Just For Your General Information) I am using SpringMVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

Close your project and replace WebContent with WebRoot in the following files

./settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
./settings/.jsdtscope

of course if you find another files replace it there too. E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="eclipse-test2">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebRoot" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="eclipse-test2"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/eclipse-test2/build/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="WebRoot"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.WebProject">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="hide" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.baseBrowserLibrary"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>
</classpath>
```

on the other hand I would recomment to use the standard folder names if you can, it just makes life easier on the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file in `.settings` directory and `wb-resource elements`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="springonly-starter">
      <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebRoot"/>
```

Look at my [spring-starter project](https://github.com/marioosh-net/spring-starter/blob/master/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component) that using Maven and need to set source-path to `src/main/webapp`. You need to set that to `/WebRoot` i think so.